# Is it possible to obtain the current URL that safari or another browser is currently using to access a website?

Tags: ios, swift, url, browser, safari

I need information on how to access the current URL that iOS Safari or any other internet browser is using to access a website. Do I need to access internet services on iOS? I would like to write code which would also run in the background all the time while the user operates the phone normally, launching the browser, etc.

I am lacking some understanding on how a URL can be accessed from an iOS browser

I haven't written any code yet as I need a more thorough understanding of the iOS framework I should use to run an app in the background from its initial installation and how to get it to monitor URLs being accessed.

No error messages to report.

Comment: Thankfully, Apple doesn't allow such horrible privacy invasion.

Comment: @rmaddy Actually I think I can retrieve the URL by implementing a Safari App Extension.

Comment: Apple won't allow this, your app will be rejected if u even managed to do so.

Comment: Even though I am using a framework that Apple provides?

Comment: @montykumar why would Apple provide app extensions if they would then reject their use in the submission to the App Store? Doesn't make sense.